# Is there a system to how the short URLs (such as by goo.gl) should be read?

Tags: url-shortening

Google's web site goo.gl (and other websites) provides a means to create shortened forms of URLs. One example of how these look like is shown below.

[image: goo.gl short url]

A problem is that it is sometimes difficult to determine if a particular URL, such as the one shown in above image, is using the letter "l" (for Lima) or the letter "I" (for India).

This is probably because the URLs are intended for copying and pasting. But sometimes a user may want to retype the URL manually. An example of this use case would be a user who obtains the URL on their PC but then forwards it through a text message.

In cases where manual replication is needed, is there a "system" that allows the reader to determine which letter should be viewed as upper case and which would be lower case?

Comment: *"though a URL is always case-insensitive"*, er, no! Domains and email addresses are case-insensitive, URLs are not. Related prove: [Mysterious Butt](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89734/mysterious-butt).

Comment: Thank you @Arjan for pointing that out. I have now corrected the text in my question.

Comment: You're still missing some parts then; https://goo.gl/qlhO3h is not the same as https://goo.gl/qlho3h

Comment: As Arjan points out, they ARE case-sensitive, so you're question has a flaw in its premise, and it's also off-topic for SU.  You'll have to use a different shortening service that's case insensitive. See here on the Web Apps SE: [Case Insensitive URL Shorteners](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10567/case-insensitive-url-shorteners)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unanswerable question as every URL shortener uses a different system. There is no standard way to generate short links.

Answer (score 0):

There is no system for this.  Sites like bitly.com simply use a hashing scheme to shorten and store the URL.  When the URL is used, the shortened URL is simply looked up by bitly and the real url is then used.  There are many reasons why URL shortening is done. Often regular unshortened links may be aesthetically unpleasing. Many times developoers put in descriptive pathes and or operators to in the URL to represent data, command structures, transaction or even session information. This may make the URL hundreds of characters long that can contain complex character patterns. These types of URLs are difficult to memorize and type out let alone distribute. Given this, long URLs must be copied-and-pasted for reliability. Therefore, short URLs are more convenient for websites or hard copy publications.